# Data-binding in a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a really basic **Angular directive** that generates a "div" that can have two states: "on" and "off".

I've naively come up with an implementation that you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/wSz2f/

The initial display is correct but the visual state is not updated when the scope state changes.

Here is the Angular directive definition:

```
var test = angular.module("test", []);
test.directive("led", function()
{   
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='led led-off' ng-class='{ \"led-on\": isOn }'>{{isOn}}</div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller)
        {
            scope.isOn = false;

            element.bind("click", function()
            {
                scope.isOn = !scope.isOn;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I guess I'm doing something stupid but what...?

Moreover, in term of design, am doing it the "Angular way" or is there better practices?

Thanks for any input. :)

---

**Final edit:**

Thanks to *Mark*, *Bertrand* and *James* for their input:

- you have to either call ***scope.$apply()*** after updating the "isOn" property to make **Angular** aware of its change (thinking about it this is how it works too in other frameworks like WPF/Silverlight with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but not in Flex with all its magic binding) or use **ng-click** like suggested by *Bertrand*
- you have to provide "**ng-class**" a condition for each CSS class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you have to fire the digest

```
element.bind("click", function()
{
    scope.isOn = !scope.isOn;
    scope.$apply();
});
```

or even better, you could use the ng-click directive in your template to change the state of isOn.

```
var test = angular.module("test", []);
test.directive("led", function()
{   
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='led led-off' ng-class='{ \"led-on\": isOn, \"led-off\": !isOn }' ng-click='onOff()'>{{isOn}}</div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller)
        {
            scope.isOn = false;

            scope.onOff = function () {
                scope.isOn = !scope.isOn;
            }
        }
   };
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7zbc/2/)

Comment: +1, but the box should turn green when `isOn` is `true`.  The following will fix that: `<div class='led' ng-class='{ \"led-on\": isOn, \"led-off\": !isOn }' ...`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was sure I've been able to use "ng-class" by only specifying the alternate class... :(

Answer (score 3):

You're code looks good. You are missing the `scope.$appy();` after updating the data. The exact internal reasons of why you need to call `scope.$apply();` are only partly clear to me. I've read a few articles on it but am no expert yet.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wSz2f/1/

Reading: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: `$apply()` is needed because event callback functions execute "outside" of Angular, so unless `$apply()` is called, an Angular digest cycle does not run.  It is the digest cycle that notices changes to Angular model data and causes views to update.  Read more on the [Overview](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) page, the Runtime section.  If you look at the diagram, event callbacks run in the "Native" gray box.  Calling `$apply` is how you get into the "AngularJS" box.  Angular directives (e.g., `ng-click`) run inside the "AngularJS" box, so `$apply()` is not needed.